# Efficient way to pass large number of argments into a constructor

Tags: c#

I am working on a project and I have an object, upon instantiation of which, will have a large number of values (20+) passed into it. I know I could make a constructor that would take in all of the values, but I am looking for a cleaner / more efficient way to do this.

Just to put this in perspective, the object is a character in a game, new instances of which are frequently created. The values assigned are attributes which are randomly generated.

Is a constructor with a large number of arguments the best way to go? Or is there a better way to do this that I don't know about? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: When a new game starts, a `List<Character>` is created and a for loop creates 10 instances of character and adds them to the list.

Comment: Are these values all public properties of your main class?

Comment: Are all the attributes of similar type?  Can you use reflection for this?  Do you mind typecasting?  There are lots of ways to do this, all have upsides and downsides...

Comment: Most are int, some are string, a couple are enum. And yes, they are all public properties.

Comment: Just curious what you mean by "Efficient" in this context?

Comment: @PinnyM probably wouldn't want to use reflection if this is a game. Reflection is expensive and would hurt performance.

Comment: What's your understanding of 'efficient' in this case? What is the *real* underlying problem you are trying to solve? Where do the parameters come from and in which form?

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for the most 'proper' way to do this. 'Efficient' was a poor choice of words in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a call that defines your game character. have users populate that class and pass it as the argument to your class.

something like this,

```
public class CharecterInfo
{ 
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public int Power {get;set;}
       public int Health{get;set;}
}

public class Charecter
{ 
     public Charecter(CharecterInfo charecterInfo)
     {
        //import values
     }
}
```

I would avoid using public properties, since your class could be used while it's not properly initialized (in a bad state) which is the job of the constructor. you should use a constructor and validate the input before allowing the user to continue.

Comment: +1 The .net framework does exactly this with `EventArgs`-derived classes... that was going to be my answer but you beat me to it!

Comment: Just a note in addition to what Keivan said, if the construction logic is too complex, you better move that part to a Factory Class...

Comment: So then what would be the best way to populate the 'CharacterInfo' class you describe. At this point most of the values are going to be randomly generated for each instance.

Comment: as Waleed said, you could have a factory class that generates `CharecterInfo` classes using random values. or you could have a method on `CharecterInfo` that would randomize the instance. maybe `CharecterInfo.Randomize()` it all depends how complicated it will be, if its fairly trivial them I would just do it in the `CharecterInfo` class. if it's gonna get complicated, create a Factory class.

Comment: +1 This is one possible outcome of the analysis & design I am suggesting in my answer.

Comment: @Waleed Can you please put some context here? Maybe an example code will help understand.

Answer (score 2):

If the properties have public setters, you can use the object [initialization syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx), e.g.:

```
Character c = new FooCharacter() {
    Name = "Ugly Monster",
    HP = 10000,
    ....,
};
```

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, this assumes that your constructor (empty or with minimal parameters) will initialize all required properties with valid data.  The initialization syntax is just syntactic sugar that sets any specified properties after the constructor has initialized the object.

Comment: this allows your class to be in an invalid state. for example if HP isn't provided but a call to DoubleHp is made. using a constructor ensures that you can't use the class without properly instantiating it.

Comment: @Keivan You're still using a constructor.  In this case, you're assuming that the empty FooCharacter constructor creates a valid Character that is in a usable state.  And, if you have certain things you need, like HP, don't have an empty constructor, have a constructor that takes the required values and initialization syntax for the optional ones.

Comment: @sammy_winter yes, that would work if your assumption is correct. in that case I would even say having a default parameter-less constructor is a must.

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends on what those arguments are...  But generally, it's not a great idea to have huge parameter lists.  This is because of the confusion it creates over which parameter is what.  An exception to this would be where you have a variable-length argument list that takes key/value pairs, allowing you to pass your data in an undefined order.

One alternative is to make another class that represents all your arguments.  You could just create an instance of this, set the relevant fields and pass that in.  To extend the idea, you might break that class up into a few classes and then provide a handful of constructors that take different combinations of those.

The useful thing with this approach is that you can have a default value for *any* of the arguments.  Normally, if you want to specify a value for something further down the argument list but use defaults for the rest, you have to fill in all the default values in between.  With this approach you can use all defaults except for the values you want to specify.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

If all of the values are required:

- Stick with the large list of parameters
- Create a new class which has all of these items as properties

If not all of the values are required and you can use the Builder-pattern:

This link describes the pattern in detail: http://cdmckay.org/blog/2009/07/03/joshua-blochs-builder-pattern-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

One possibility lies in OOAD itself.  Character attributes sound like a big enough concern to be the responsibility of a distinct class with which your character class collaborates.

A quick [CRC](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/crcModel.htm) analysis of your domain may help identify one or more newly distinguished responsibilities & corresponding types that are missing presently.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method that returns a class instance. Perhaps even in that class itself.

Something like:

```
public class Character
{
    public string Name;
    public int Level;
    static Random random = new Random();

    public static Character CreateNew()
    {
        Character newOne = new Character();
        newOne.Level = random.Next(1, 5);
        newOne.Name = (random.Next(1, 2) == 1) ? "Me" : "You";
        return newOne;
    }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: disregard that comment.

Comment: @DennisE Or if you can't, you can use Jimmy's answer. Or just stick with a constructor with many parameters, of course :)

Comment: Given this method, how should I go about naming the new instance of the object since the method will be called many times?

Comment: @DennisE a) This would be a question any way you decide to create them. b) That depends on what exactly you're doing with the characters. A `List` of `Character`'s comes to mind. But sometimes a class instance is created, subscribes to events, and its code-name disappears because it's not needed anymore - anything else about the instance will be handled in the event handlers which will refer to it as `sender` (common practice).

Comment: A `List` is what I'm using. I have a for loop that creates 10 new instances of the class when the game starts and adds them to the list.